# Async server-side rendering using redux & react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I am having serious difficulty getting a working server-side rendering solution using `React`, `Redux`, `Redux-Thunk` and `React-Router`.

At the moment, my solution works on the client-side following the basic guidelines and this post: https://codepen.io/stowball/post/a-dummy-s-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react. For the scope of simplicity, I will be using the code from that blog as my example. The only alteration is that I have added a `console.log("X");` to the reducer function `items` so that I know when it is called. The resultant function is:

```
export function items(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            console.log('X');
            return action.items;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and I also set the `itemsFetchData` function to return the promise, becoming:

```
export function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((items) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(items)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

As I need server-side rendering. I setup Express to consume my middleware `handleRender` which in turn calls `renderFullPage` that returns the HTML string. The Express implementation can be assumed correct. My `handleRender` looks like the below

```
export function handleRender(req, res) {
  // Create a new Redux store instance
  const store = configureStore();

  const { dispatch } = store;

  dispatch(itemsFetchData(''http://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items'')).then(() => {
    console.log("Y");
    // Render the component to a string
    const html = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div id="app">
          <StaticRouter context={{}} location={req.url}>
            <Main />
          </StaticRouter>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );

    // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
    const preloadedState = store.getState();

    // Send the rendered page back to the client
    res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));
  });
}
```

Using the above code, `Y` is printed to the console, but `X` is never printed, meaning the reducer function is not being called. If I remove the `then` from the promise in my handleRender, thus becoming:

```
dispatch(itemsFetchData(''http://5826ed963900d612000138bd.mockapi.io/items''));
console.log("Y");
// ... remaining code remains unaltered
```

The reducer function is being called correctly and the Redux store updated correctly, however since this is asynchronous the `handleRender` would have returned the HTML already.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's been a long day.

Comment: I'd recommend to use [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) .The repo provides many examples (including usage of redux) and the server is customizable as well.

Comment: Is it too late to challenge the requirement of having server-side rendering in the first place? I worked on a project with next.js and redux and it was a pain in the ass to do stuff like fetching a logged in users account data before returning a server-rendered page. We ended up building a normal SPA.

Server-side rendering is nice for SEO-relevant pages and mobile websites for faster initial page load. For everything else, especially pages with user authentication, it's not so beneficial.

Comment: Server side rendering is a requirement. I won't go into the merits of SSR as it is off topic, but I agree that since using react/redux it feels like it is much more complicated than it should/used to be.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the confusion was caused because the reducer was injected *after* the `itemsFetchData` was called. The problem was only noted when using `then` because without it, the component `Main` which injected the reducer was still included and everything seemed normal. When it was relying on the `then` I ended up with the `then` unable to dispatch because there was no reducer and the `Main` component not included because it was waiting for the dispatch.

To solve the problem, I have included the reducer in my `combineReducers`.

Like I said, it was a long day.